# HTTP Response How To Send HTML file

Tags: java, html, http, sockets

I am writing a webserver that returns static html pages. In response to the request GET /path/to/file/index.html HTTP/1.0, I am supposed to return index.html. I am writing this in Java, so I am basically returning the page via socket.outputstream. However, I don't know how to return an html file via outputstream. Do I have to open the input file, read it line by line, and then print it to socket.outputstream? Or is there a shortcut way of sending an html file as a HTTP response? Thanks!

Comment: socket's use those streams to communicate - if you need to send any information of any kind through a socket write it out as a string.

Comment: Have you tried using servlets? If not, why?

Comment: BTW you might want to wrap your hand around `java.nio`, especially `SocketChannel`, `FileChannel`, and `Pipe`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need to use streams, then yes, you need to copy the data yourself. You can find example code [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/File-Input-Output/copyCompletelyInputStreaminputOutputStreamoutput.htm) and [here](http://www.developerfeed.com/android/howto/copy-bytes-inputstream-outputstream-android).

You can however use [`SocketChannel.open()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html#open%28java.net.SocketAddress%29) from [java.nio](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/package-summary.html) to open the socket, [`FileChannel.open()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#open%28java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.OpenOption...%29) to open the file and then [`FileChannel.transferTo()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/FileChannel.html#transferTo%28long,%20long,%20java.nio.channels.WritableByteChannel%29) method to transfer all file's data to the socket.